# Parse html values in the server in express.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I don't know what this is not working when it work in my previous pages.

```
input.form-control(type="text", name="names[]", autocomplete="off")
```

I want to retrieve that value in my server. In my other pages I use this

```
console.log("value " + req.body["names[]"]);
```

I typically get an array of names. Now for some reason all I get is undefined I have tried for hours I just don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`req.body` is `undefined` by default according to the [Express Docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body).  You'll need a middleware like [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) to grab pieces of `req`.

1) `npm install body-parser`
2) Towards the top of server file - `var bodyParser = require('body-parser');`
3) after `var app = express()` include `app.use(bodyParser.json());`